# How to create android studio layout folder to specific dimension? error getting invalid configuration '1080x2340'

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

My application UI doesn't fit on a 1080x2340 resolution device. I want to create a layout folder to specify these resolution phones. I create the layout folder layout-1080x2340 but I have to get error **invalid configuration '1080x2340'**.please help to fix this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [Android official guidelines](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#available-width) of supporting screen sizes represents, you should use **one qualifier** for width to support higher resolutions, and only if height is a concern you can add height qualifier:

> If the available height is a concern for you, then you can do the same using the "available height" qualifier. For example, layout-h600dp for screens with at least 600dp of screen height.

But if you're insisting on using both qualifiers you can do it as so (assuming 600dp x 600dp):

```
layout-w600dp-h600dp
```

Although it is discouraged you can also [restrict your screen support](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution).